# Extracting a Win7 Install disk from a pre-install

Tags: windows-7, installation

I bought an Asus netbook with Windows 7 pre-installed.  The install files are on a 16 GB hidden partition on the hard drive and from what I understand I would have to pay something like $50 to get a physical install disk from Asus.

Is there any way I can extract a usable install disk from the hidden install partition?

Comment: I believe you can access the partition from some bios setting and then use it to restore the machine

Comment: @shake he's asking about creating a DVD or USB image off the partition. Probably in case the disk dies, recovery partitions are useless when your HDD fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, manually making an install disk from the restore partition is difficult if not impossible for most users.

Some OEM PC makers have a program on the PC to make (burn) the recovery discs yourself, look for a program on the All Programs list, possibly in an ASUS folder
If it does not have this feature:

Make a full disk image of the current hard drive [using Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/), this can be used to restore to a new hard drive if necessary, I do this for every new PC I own. I then make additional images of the drive as time rocks on. Acronis is very powerful software and can do many types of disk images and backup routines.

If you want a free alternative to Acronis, [there is Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx), not as powerful as Acronis but can make disk images for restore purposes.